# Publish Kernel Density Layer Which is Transparent

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-pro, kernel-density

I am using ArcGIS Pro 1.4 to publish web layers which are the result of a kernel density operation.  I am using mining data from MRDS for China.  The raster layers were created and published to AGOL here: http://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/nAQVsl698blIdU3d/arcgis/rest/services/Major_Mineral_Extraction_in_China_WTL1/MapServer.

When they are activated in either application (Pro or AGOL) all but one of the layers is not fully transparent in the areas of the published extent which do not contain the output cells.  To see this, turn on all of the layers at once.  Only the layer KernelD_MRDS_TI is transparent in those areas.  This prevents proper visualization of the combined layers when they are all active.  As a result, the slight grey tint accumulates and blurs out the entire basemap.  I created all of the layers with the same tool and with the exact parameters with the exception of the population field used.  Here is the vector point data used in the kernel density tool: http://services1.arcgis.com/nAQVsl698blIdU3d/arcgis/rest/services/Major_Mineral_Extraction_in_China_WFL1/FeatureServer.

The clip here shows the parameters used for the kernel density tool:

[image]

I would like all of them to be as fully transparent in those regions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After exploring this a little more I was able to adjust the symbology on the layers to make the end of the color ramp fully transparent.  This seemed to solve the problem.  I then republished the tiles and they serve the originaly intended purpose.